# os.GetEnv() dosen't work after set env variable

Tags: go, environment-variables

I have the case dosen't work function

> os.GetEnv()

I have set a variable in my system ADDR="192.168.1.100" trought file **.bashrc** and **.profile**. So if I open terminal and type below command, I get good result

> $ echo $ADDR
>
> 192.168.1.100

Why in below very simply program I get Error if variable is correct set in system ?

```
func main(){
    addr := os.Getenv("ADDR")
    if addr == "" {
        return errors.New("missing addres")
    }
}
```

I also restarted IDE a many times. Tried write in terminal again

> $ env ADDR="192.168.1.100"

but still this same effect.

Comment: restarting your IDE probably isn't going to spawn a new shell with the new environment variables, depending on how you start it, you may need to log out and log back in again. Run your program from the the command line in a new shell.

Comment: Did you restart your PC?

Comment: Did you check for typos? Setting `ADD` and reading `ADDR` don't influence each other.

Comment: Restart PC was be neccessary. I thought that if I set env in system via termnal evrythings should be works.

Comment: `env` doesn't _set_ anything, it either prints the variables, or alters a new environment. All your `env` command does is echo the variable you set with the rest of the environment variables. You should also only set these  `.profile`, not `.bashrc`

Comment: You may be missing an `export` in your `~/.bashrc`, i.e. it should be `export ADDR=192.168.1.100` if you want the variable to be available in your Go app.

Answer (score 12):

I think the problem is likely that you are not exporting the variable, so the sub process (i.e. you ide, shell, is not getting it).

```
ADDR="192.168.1.100" go run main.go
```

or

```
export ADD="192.168.1.100"
go run main.go
```

Comment: I had a similar problem, but this is particular to have zsh or bash script environment variables. One of my zsh files had `ADD='192.168.1.100'` instead of `export ADD='192.168.1.100'. `

Comment: If using GoLand, one can add an environment variable in run/debug configuration (Environment field).

Answer (score 7):

We have to load env before trying to get it.
So,I used a package named `godotenv` to load env.
To install godotenv

```
$ go get github.com/joho/godotenv
```

then,

```
// load
err := godotenv.Load()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("err loading: %v", err)
    }

// get
addr := os.Getenv("ADDR")
if addr == "" {
    return errors.New("missing addres")
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I had same problem and for me it's because I run the program with sudo.

I checked the environment variable as a normal user. But run the program as root. So their environment could not be the same.

Answer (score 1):

you can have your env variables in a .env file and export them when you run it like this:

export `less .env | xargs`; go run cmd/main.go

Answer (score 0):

if you go program is another app like program in Mac, then use following to set it:

```
sudo launchctl setenv <env var> <env var value>
```

Answer (score 0):

I just had this issue and I solved it by not running the program as root. I'm not sure of the cause, but it works now!